# Trouble Setting up Apache for PHP

Tags: php, apache

I am super new to PHP. I am trying to setup my apache development server, and I am having a bunch of trouble. I installed XAMPP but cannot get apache to startup properly. I read that I might be having a port issue, however I did update my port from the default (80) to 8080 ("Listen" in config) but that has not done the trick.

I am sharing my logs from my attempt today here. Thankful for any help:

```
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Fri Jan 24 07:46:56.159871 2020] [:emerg] [pid 6968:tid 640] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 08:54:56.137764 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 57160:tid 668] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 08:54:56.215556 2020] [core:warn] [pid 57160:tid 668] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 08:54:56.223538 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 57160:tid 668] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 08:54:56.236064 2020] [:emerg] [pid 57160:tid 668] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 08:55:09.485567 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 46248:tid 640] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 08:55:09.533489 2020] [core:warn] [pid 46248:tid 640] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 08:55:09.540470 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 46248:tid 640] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 08:55:09.542449 2020] [:emerg] [pid 46248:tid 640] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 08:56:43.925777 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 50856:tid 664] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 08:56:44.023296 2020] [core:warn] [pid 50856:tid 664] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 08:56:44.032271 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 50856:tid 664] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 08:56:44.034269 2020] [:emerg] [pid 50856:tid 664] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 08:57:16.913391 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 51804:tid 644] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 08:57:16.991182 2020] [core:warn] [pid 51804:tid 644] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 08:57:16.998164 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 51804:tid 644] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 08:57:17.000160 2020] [:emerg] [pid 51804:tid 644] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 08:57:24.342253 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 5272:tid 632] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 08:57:24.453953 2020] [core:warn] [pid 5272:tid 632] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 08:57:24.493888 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 5272:tid 632] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 08:57:24.495842 2020] [:emerg] [pid 5272:tid 632] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 08:57:28.376224 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 53920:tid 648] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 08:57:28.473234 2020] [core:warn] [pid 53920:tid 648] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 08:57:28.480216 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 53920:tid 648] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 08:57:28.482213 2020] [:emerg] [pid 53920:tid 648] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 08:57:31.590044 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 54316:tid 664] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 08:57:31.728184 2020] [core:warn] [pid 54316:tid 664] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 08:57:31.737214 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 54316:tid 664] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 08:57:31.739193 2020] [:emerg] [pid 54316:tid 664] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 09:09:20.690919 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 51004:tid 660] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:09:20.809505 2020] [core:warn] [pid 51004:tid 660] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 09:09:20.819483 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 51004:tid 660] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 09:09:20.822437 2020] [:emerg] [pid 51004:tid 660] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 09:10:01.318296 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 3292:tid 656] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:10:01.408082 2020] [core:warn] [pid 3292:tid 656] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 09:10:01.416059 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 3292:tid 656] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 09:10:01.419052 2020] [:emerg] [pid 3292:tid 656] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 09:23:30.285945 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 55576:tid 548] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:23:30.388558 2020] [core:warn] [pid 55576:tid 548] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 09:23:30.396537 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 55576:tid 548] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 09:23:30.400527 2020] [:emerg] [pid 55576:tid 548] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 09:31:45.633613 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 56000:tid 628] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:31:45.712419 2020] [core:warn] [pid 56000:tid 628] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 09:31:45.720398 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 56000:tid 628] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 09:31:45.724387 2020] [:emerg] [pid 56000:tid 628] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 09:33:44.117281 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 55824:tid 640] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:33:44.272055 2020] [core:warn] [pid 55824:tid 640] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 09:33:44.281034 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 55824:tid 640] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 09:33:44.284025 2020] [:emerg] [pid 55824:tid 640] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 09:33:46.667930 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 54980:tid 644] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:33:46.783160 2020] [core:warn] [pid 54980:tid 644] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 09:33:46.792138 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 54980:tid 644] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 09:33:46.795129 2020] [:emerg] [pid 54980:tid 644] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 09:33:50.009963 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 56348:tid 588] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:33:50.129864 2020] [core:warn] [pid 56348:tid 588] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 09:33:50.144823 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 56348:tid 588] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:34:11.021745 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 55408:tid 164] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:34:11.147787 2020] [core:warn] [pid 55408:tid 164] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 09:34:11.155764 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 55408:tid 164] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 09:34:11.158757 2020] [:emerg] [pid 55408:tid 164] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 09:43:04.485539 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 49976:tid 648] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:43:04.595250 2020] [core:warn] [pid 49976:tid 648] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 09:43:04.603229 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 49976:tid 648] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 09:43:04.606219 2020] [:emerg] [pid 49976:tid 648] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 09:43:08.438563 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 39268:tid 680] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:27.100004 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 47440:tid 476] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:27.208956 2020] [core:warn] [pid 47440:tid 476] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:27.273785 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 47440:tid 476] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:27.282758 2020] [:emerg] [pid 47440:tid 476] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:29.407186 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 42256:tid 168] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:29.512412 2020] [core:warn] [pid 42256:tid 168] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:29.521389 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 42256:tid 168] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:29.523383 2020] [:emerg] [pid 42256:tid 168] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:30.453977 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 50896:tid 664] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:30.557707 2020] [core:warn] [pid 50896:tid 664] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:30.586628 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 50896:tid 664] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:30.598592 2020] [:emerg] [pid 50896:tid 664] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:32.543035 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 41088:tid 156] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:32.638125 2020] [core:warn] [pid 41088:tid 156] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:32.680009 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 41088:tid 156] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:32.687988 2020] [:emerg] [pid 41088:tid 156] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:33.430999 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 55392:tid 624] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:33.550910 2020] [core:warn] [pid 55392:tid 624] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:33.586821 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 55392:tid 624] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:33.593795 2020] [:emerg] [pid 55392:tid 624] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:36.798802 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 39660:tid 656] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:36.925490 2020] [core:warn] [pid 39660:tid 656] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:36.970372 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 39660:tid 656] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 09:47:36.978347 2020] [:emerg] [pid 39660:tid 656] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 09:48:08.516852 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 49168:tid 556] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:48:08.588180 2020] [core:warn] [pid 49168:tid 556] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 09:48:08.626081 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 49168:tid 556] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 09:48:08.635054 2020] [:emerg] [pid 49168:tid 556] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 09:48:09.894746 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 47520:tid 624] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:48:09.989032 2020] [core:warn] [pid 47520:tid 624] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 09:48:10.030922 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 47520:tid 624] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 09:48:10.043885 2020] [:emerg] [pid 47520:tid 624] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 09:48:12.145872 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 54692:tid 536] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:48:12.248879 2020] [core:warn] [pid 54692:tid 536] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 09:48:12.258855 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 54692:tid 536] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 09:48:12.261846 2020] [:emerg] [pid 54692:tid 536] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 09:48:26.860043 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 49976:tid 644] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 09:48:26.962778 2020] [core:warn] [pid 49976:tid 644] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 09:48:26.973741 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 49976:tid 644] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 09:48:26.979727 2020] [:emerg] [pid 49976:tid 644] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 10:24:06.381001 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 2908:tid 680] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 10:24:06.462295 2020] [core:warn] [pid 2908:tid 680] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 10:24:06.478253 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 2908:tid 680] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 10:24:06.484237 2020] [:emerg] [pid 2908:tid 680] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 10:24:31.272001 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 8128:tid 632] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 10:24:31.319874 2020] [core:warn] [pid 8128:tid 632] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 10:24:31.326853 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 8128:tid 632] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 10:24:31.329200 2020] [:emerg] [pid 8128:tid 632] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 10:24:44.843933 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 5324:tid 644] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 10:24:44.892801 2020] [core:warn] [pid 5324:tid 644] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 10:24:44.900781 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 5324:tid 644] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 10:24:44.902776 2020] [:emerg] [pid 5324:tid 644] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 10:24:58.345914 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 8272:tid 560] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 10:24:58.414253 2020] [core:warn] [pid 8272:tid 560] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 10:24:58.436186 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 8272:tid 560] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 10:24:58.443173 2020] [:emerg] [pid 8272:tid 560] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 10:25:01.342659 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 9996:tid 640] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 10:25:01.426985 2020] [core:warn] [pid 9996:tid 640] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 10:25:01.432972 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 9996:tid 640] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 10:25:01.434931 2020] [:emerg] [pid 9996:tid 640] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Feb 01 10:25:03.283909 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 15292:tid 632] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Feb 01 10:25:03.350125 2020] [core:warn] [pid 15292:tid 632] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Feb 01 10:25:03.372111 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 15292:tid 632] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'vcruntime140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.16 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Feb 01 10:25:03.379054 2020] [:emerg] [pid 15292:tid 632] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
```

Answer (score 9):

Your vcruntime140.dll lib is outdated.

PHP 7.4.x requires Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019 which can be downloaded here:

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Scroll down to 'Other Tools and Frameworks'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I changed the ports, restarted the services but in vein, only worked for me when I updated the Microsoft Visual c++ files[image: Image will help for the solution of this problem]