# XAMPP ERROR : Apache shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: php, apache, server, xampp, localhost

I was working on my new website and i updated my computer to the new version of windows 10. Opened again XAMPP Control Panel and it gave me an Apache Error. I opened the error logs :

````
[Sat Mar 13 15:34:48.897081 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 12988:tid 592] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.28 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Mar 13 15:34:48.899080 2021] [:emerg] [pid 12988:tid 592] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Mar 13 15:36:03.212389 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 12164:tid 572] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Mar 13 15:36:03.272591 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 12164:tid 572] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.28 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Mar 13 15:36:03.272591 2021] [:emerg] [pid 12164:tid 572] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting
[Sat Mar 13 15:55:42.529151 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 6600:tid 584] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Mar 13 15:55:42.581127 2021] [core:warn] [pid 6600:tid 584] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Sat Mar 13 15:55:42.588118 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 6600:tid 584] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
PHP Warning:  'C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\VCRUNTIME140.dll' 14.0 is not compatible with this PHP build linked with 14.28 in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Mar 13 15:55:42.590101 2021] [:emerg] [pid 6600:tid 584] AH00020: Configuration Failed, exiting```

Does anyone have any idea of what the problem is?
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble Setting up Apache for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018357/trouble-setting-up-apache-for-php)

Comment: Your problem is exactly like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60018357/trouble-setting-up-apache-for-php . See the top voted answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping